# Request Processing failed with null pointer exception because Cannot invoke Service class as it is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

Request Processing failed with null pointer exception because  Cannot invoke Service class as it is null.

I am trying to write the test cases for my controller class.

This is my User Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(URLConstants.User)
@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({ @Autowired }))
public class UsersController {
  private final UserMapper mapper;
  private final UserService userService;
  

  @PutMapping("/{id}")
  public UserDTO update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody UserUpdateRequest userRequest) {
    log.debug("PUT /users/" + id + " with data" + userRequest);
    User user = CurrentUserContext.getCurrentUser();
    mapper.mergeToUser(userRequest, user);
    user = userService.update(user);
    return mapper.mapDTO(user);
  }

  
}
```

For this This is my Test Class

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = UsersController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UsersControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserMapper userMapper;

  @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Mock
    private CurrentUserContext currentUserContext;

    @InjectMocks
    private UsersController usersController;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();




    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test successful user update")
    public void testUpdateUserSuccess() throws Exception {
        // Prepare test data
        Long userId = 1L;
        UserUpdateRequest userUpdateRequest = new UserUpdateRequest();
        userUpdateRequest.setFirstName("John");
        userUpdateRequest.setLastName("Doe");

        User updatedUser = new User();
        updatedUser.setId(userId);
        updatedUser.setFirstName(userUpdateRequest.getFirstName());
        updatedUser.setLastName(userUpdateRequest.getLastName());
        updatedUser.setStatus(UserStatus.Active);
        updatedUser.setCreatedDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        updatedUser.setUpdatedDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        // Mock the service method
        when(userService.update(updatedUser)).thenReturn(updatedUser);

        // Perform the request and verify the response
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(usersController).build();
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/users/{id}", userId)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userUpdateRequest)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
                /*.andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(userId))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstName").value(userUpdateRequest.getFirstName()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastName").value(userUpdateRequest.getLastName()));*/
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test invalid user update request")
    public void testUpdateUserInvalidRequest() throws Exception {
        // Prepare test data
        Long userId = 1L;
        UserUpdateRequest userUpdateRequest = new UserUpdateRequest();
        // Empty update request

        // Perform the request and verify the response
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(usersController).build();
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/users/{id}", userId)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userUpdateRequest)))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }


}
```

Now even though I am `@MockBean.  private UserService userService;` I am getting `this.userService is null.

```
Jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.app.users.services.UserService.update(com.app.users.models.User)" because "this.userService" is null
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:925)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)


…….
…….



Cannot invoke "com.app.users.services.UserService.update(com.app.users.models.User)" because "this.userService" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.app.users.services.UserService.update(com.app.users.models.User)" because "this.userService" is null
    at com.app.users.controllers.UsersController.update(UsersController.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:925)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
```

What could be the possible reason for this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a breakdown of the error and how to fix it:

Understanding the Error:

Null Pointer Exception: This is a common error in programming that occurs when you try to use a variable that hasn't been assigned a value (it's "null"). In this case, the variable holding the service class is null, so you can't call its methods.
Service Class: This is a class that provides specific functionality to your program. It probably does some important task related to processing requests.
Troubleshooting Steps:

Identify Where the Service Class Should Be Created: Look for the part of your code where this service class is supposed to be initialized. It might be in a configuration file, a dependency injection framework, or within your code itself.

Ensure Proper Initialization: Make sure the code that creates the service class is running correctly. If it's in a configuration file, double-check for typos or errors. If it's handled by a framework, verify that the framework is set up properly.

Check for Conditional Logic: If there's code that might prevent the service class from being created under certain conditions, review that logic. For example, maybe a configuration setting determines whether the service is enabled or disabled.

Debugging Tips: Use debugging tools provided by your programming environment to step through your code line by line and see where the null value is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Use `@WebMvcTest`

Your test is all wrong.

There are 2 `UsersController` instances in your test.

- One is created via SpringBootTest which brings up entire application context - controllers, services etc. Some beans are overriden via `@MockBean`. This controller uses your mock service.
- The second one is created by Mockito and `@InjectMocks`. `@MockBean` are not injected into this service.

There are also 2 `MockMvc` instances:

- One created via `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` and injected via `@Autowired`
- Second created manually in your test method

In your test method you are using manually created `MockMvc` which makes requests to `UsersController` created by Mockito, which is not properly initialized - and you get NPE.

**Solution**

Use only one controller and one mockMvc.

However you can improve the test even further. You don't need entire spring context as:

- you are trying to test web layer of your app
- you are testing only one controller
- the services it uses are mocks

This is an ideal use case for `@WebMvcTest`.

- Replace `@SpringBootTest` with `@WebMvcTest`
- `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` is imported via `@WebMvcTest`, so remove it as well
- Remove `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`
- Do not create your own `MockMvc`

See:

- [Testing the Web Layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web) in Spring Docs
- [8. Unit Testing With @WebMvcTest](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#unit-testing-with-webmvctest) in Baeldung tutorials